# Archiving Log Files by Zipping/Moving in Shell/Solaris

Tags: bash, shell, unix, solaris

I am trying to moving and archive folder but things are not going as it seems.

```
CURRDATEforARCHIVE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
PASTDATEforARCHIVE=`date -d "now - 7 days" "+%Y-%m-%d"`
mkdir $status_destpath/${PASTDATEforARCHIVE}TO${CURRDATEforARCHIVE}
echo "Directory Created"

cd $status_srcpath
for f in *
do 
mv $f $status_destpath/${PASTDATEforARCHIVE}TO${CURRDATEforARCHIVE}
done
echo "Moving all files done"

zip "${PASTDATEforARCHIVE}TO${CURRDATEforARCHIVE}.zip"     "$status_destpath/${PASTDATEforARCHIVE}TO${CURRDATEforARCHIVE}"
echo "Zipping Done."

echo "Verification in progress."
# Verify that zip has been created.
if [ -f "${PASTDATEforARCHIVE}TO${CURRDATEforARCHIVE}.zip" ]
then
    echo "Zip creation pass. Deletion in progress."
    rm -rf $status_destpath/${PASTDATEforARCHIVE}TO${CURRDATEforARCHIVE}
else
    printf "Zip creation failed '%s'\n"
fi

echo "Archival End."
```

The PAST DATE does not seem to work, and the files are not getting archived either, and the location of the archive folder is at the src, how can I archive and have it at the destination?

Comment: what is value in $status_srcpath? where it is set? same goes for $status_destpath

Comment: Sorry, I did not include them as I didn't think they were important, but here it is,    status_srcpath=/apps/GMST/Scripts/LMS/logs
status_destpath=/apps/GMST/Scripts/archive/logs

Comment: try ${status_srcpath} and ${status_destpath} instead of $status_srcpath and $status_destpath. You are not facing error. Please share the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need GNU `date` to be able to use the GNU specific options defining the `PASTDATEforARCHIVE` variable.

Depending on the Solaris release you are using, GNU date might be located in the directories `/usr/gnu/bin`, `/usr/sfw/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/csw/bin`, or `/usr/has/bin` ...

If missing, you need to install GNU `date` or use a different method to set your variable.

Comment: Sorry, I am relatively new to unix systems, how would I invoke Date in any of these places?

Comment: Just use the full path, eg : `/usr/sfw/bin/date`.